# Brunch.io Configuration For VueJS Components

Tags: vue.js, brunch

I have a VueJS component which contains JS, CSS, and a Template.  I’m working inside a Phoenix/Elixir skeleton.

I need to configure Brunch to concatenate the JS to vendor.js, the CSS to vendor.css and the Template to templates/template_name/template_name.html.eex.

Can it be done? If so, how?

**Sample VueJS component:**

```
<style>
    .test_component h2 {

    }
</style>

<template>
    <div class="test_component">

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        data: function () {
            return {

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Current brunch-config.js:**

```
exports.config = {
  // See http://brunch.io/#documentation for docs.
  files: {
    javascripts: {
//      joinTo: "js/app.js"

      // To use a separate vendor.js bundle, specify two files path
      // https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/stable/docs/config.md#files
       joinTo: {
        "js/app.js": /^(web\/static\/js)/,
        "js/vendor.js": /^(web\/static\/vendor)|(deps)/
       }
      //
      // To change the order of concatenation of files, explicitly mention here
      // https://github.com/brunch/brunch/tree/master/docs#concatenation
      // order: {
      //   before: [
      //     "web/static/vendor/js/jquery-2.1.1.js",
      //     "web/static/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      //   ]
      // }
    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: "css/app.css"
    },
    templates: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
    }
  },

  conventions: {
    // This option sets where we should place non-css and non-js assets in.
    // By default, we set this to "/web/static/assets". Files in this directory
    // will be copied to `paths.public`, which is "priv/static" by default.
    assets: /^(web\/static\/assets)/
  },

  // Phoenix paths configuration
  paths: {
    // Dependencies and current project directories to watch
    watched: [
      "deps/phoenix/web/static",
      "deps/phoenix_html/web/static",
      "web/static",
      "test/static"
    ],

    // Where to compile files to
    public: "priv/static"
  },

  // Configure your plugins
  plugins: {
    babel: {
      // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
      ignore: [/web\/static\/vendor/]
    }
  },

  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "js/app.js": ["web/static/js/app"]
    }
  },

  npm: {
    enabled: true,
    // Whitelist the npm deps to be pulled in as front-end assets.
    // All other deps in package.json will be excluded from the bundle.
    whitelist: ["phoenix", "phoenix_html", "vue"]
  }
};
```

Comment: The config seems to be right. What is the question here?

Comment: For your Vue component you can take a look at https://github.com/nblackburn/vue-brunch